# How would I be able to input a string on a search bar?

Tags: c, windows, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I'm programming in C and got my program to open up a search engine (Microsoft Edge), but I still can't figure out how to get the user's input to be entered in the search bar. I'm wondering if there's an easy way to accomplish my goal?

---

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define size 100

int main(){
    // Not sure if I should use (int argc, char **argv, char **envp)

    char input[size];

    Printf("Please input your search!");
    scanf("%s", &input);

    
    system("\"\"c:\\program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe\" \"www.google.com\"\"");
    
    
    
return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: You can't. That would require controlling the behavior of another application, which is quite complex. Instead, you can just open Edge with the URL `https://google.com/search?q=user+input+here`.

Comment: **@marcoBonelli** So how do people create programs that interact with games and trading bots and such?? I thought entering a string in a search engine and searching it would be easier.

Comment: Either the game offers a way to write plugins or they reverse-engineer the game for a lot of time and inject code into it. It's quite complicated.

Comment: **@marcoBonelli** Well that sucks, I guess I can't make my intended goal of making a trading bot for Robinhood that buys and sell Dogecoin. Would this be possible if I change the programming language or figure out how to interact with the inspect element?

Comment: For that particular purpose you can write a browser extension. That'd be doable.

Comment: **@marcoBonelli** Ok awesome thanks for the advice. Also, would I be able to write a browser extension using C, or do I have to pick a different language such as JavaScript?

Comment: Yeah, you would need JavaScript.

Comment: From the description, it looks like you want to launch the Edge browser, visit any search engine, enter the user input and search it. This is generally known as browser automation. I suggest you refer to the [Use WebDriver (Chromium) for test automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp). Please refer to this [Sample code](https://justpaste.it/98ndm). You can use a web driver with the languages like Python, Java, C#, Ruby, JavaScript. Let me know if you have further questions about it. I will try to provide further suggestions.